# Game of science!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, science

These titles are obfuscated by science.

```
429068 89 (110/2)88(31/2)8716
5758936 89 61(13/2)53(60/2)16
```

Could someone clarify them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a

> Periodic Table cipher

And we need to decipher

> `42 90 68   8 9   (110/2) 88 (31/2) 8 7 16`
>  `5759836   8 9   61 (13/2) 53 (60/2) 16`

It is deciphered to

> Mother of Dragons

and

> 'Breackr of chains' which can be written approximately as 'Breaker of Chains'.

And the numbers that are divided by two shows that

> If it is 31/2 then 31 decrypts to Ga and as it is divided by two, so we need to consider only one letter out of G and A.

Comment: I think you want a space between the 6 and 1 in the bottom row

Comment: Yeah, I spelled breaker breakr for easyness.  +1

Comment: @BrentHackers But the symbol for the element on 98 is Cf. So it is not possible for it being 'A' as in Breakr.

Comment: You're right!  Typo... (98 = 89) So sorry!  fixed. ( B 5 Re 75 Ac 89 Kr 36 )